# Creating a grid-style Tumblr theme using inline-block?

Tags: css-float, tumblr, css

im attempting to make a grid-style Tumblr theme using inline-block, but there have been some... complications. The posts are automatically aligning with each other vertically. That wouldn't be a problem if they were all the same dimensions, but the posts vary between heights. To sum it up, Im looking to create two columns of posts [of varied heights] that do NOT have any kind of vertical alignment. I've tried a number of different solutions, but nothing seems to work.

The first link is the JSFIDDLE.

[This is how it currently looks](http://jsfiddle.net/88h4mkmy/) versus [how I would like it to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiyxR.jpg)

**CSS**

```
#entries {
width: 600px;
{block:PermalinkPage}width: 630px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
position: relative;
padding: 0px;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.posts {
position: relative;
text-align: left;
background: {color:Posts}; 
width: 250px;
{block:PermalinkPage}width: 500px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
margin: 20px;
padding: 0px; 
word-wrap: break-word;
display: inline-block;
clear: right;
}

.posts nth-child(even) {
float: right;
}
```

Any tips or possible alternatives would be excellent because I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Im starting to think the vertical alignment is just inherent to inline-block?

Comment: This layout is tough to achieve using only CSS. A javascript plugin like masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) might be helpful.

Comment: Metafizzy and Gridster are two more awesome libraries

Comment: @iharby: That semi-colon was apparently the answer to all my problems, hahaha. Its all working beautifully now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @SteveSanders: Thanks for the tips, man. I was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to using JS, but if all else were to fail, Id have had to fall back onto it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Only css is hard but you can use a javascript plugin *gridalicious* here is the link to github https://github.com/suprb/Grid-A-Licious

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="../">
        <p>Text </p>
    </div>
<div>
```

Here an example http://jsfiddle.net/wqfoku85/